# Do replicators ultimately lead to a money free state?

Tags: science-fiction-genre, society

In all the two settings I've seen with some form or matter-matter or energy-matter converters (replicators) they both have either no money system (federation in star trek) or some other form of currency (Days in Strata).

Is this sort of society an inevitable by-product of replicators, are they unrelated or is it not as common as I think?

Comment: Related: [Don't replicators make the Ferengi rather pointless?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8471/dont-replicators-make-the-ferengi-rather-pointless)

Comment: [I hope we'll find out soon...](http://www.extremetech.com/electronics/115185-the-pirate-bay-declares-3d-printed-physibles-as-the-next-frontier-of-piracy)

Comment: A phrase that you may want for searching the many fictional and essay-like approaches to this questions is "post-scarcity". And a *lot* has been said on the subject just in SF. Ian Banks' Culture books feature a quasi-Utopian society far beyond the age of scarcity. Fred Pohl envisioned a less pleasant version in "The Midas Curse". Some authors have posited that an abrupt transition could have disruptive effects to the level of generating complete anarchy.

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke said that in the future, the unit of currency would be the kilowatt-hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a money-free society assumes unrestricted access to replicator technology, which seems naive.  Nation states may restrict access to the technology, as is done in Joe Haldeman's novel [*Forever Peace*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forever_Peace), and then wage wars over the technology and the repercussions of it on their economies.  This seems completely logical to me; disruptive technologies are  outlawed and fought over even today.  I expect more draconian bans as technology multiplies the potential force that an individual can command.

Answer (score 8):

Methinks not.

There's always **something** that can't be replicated, whatever kind of replicators you use. And because of the good old human nature, in the given society, the very same thing will become expensive (in any kind of currency) and people will want to have it.

Consider a few historical examples. Nowadays we take a lot of things for granted, things which would cost a fortune a few centuries ago. Yet we still have a monetary system and social inequalities. The most mundane example I can think of is *pepper*. I just had a breakfast with the amount of pepper which my great-great-great-grandfather couldn't have earned in years. The fact that it could be produced ad transported *almost free of charge* compared to a few centuries ago didn't really break the society. Ok, there was the whole thing with the industrial revolution and rise of capitalism and communism, but neither of these made currency obsolete. Not even communism, although in that system *money* and *currency* weren't necessarily the same thing. There are many other examples like cheaper energy, faster communication, etc.

The reasons why diamonds and precious metals were always expensive are they couldn't be produced easily as food or other materials. And in Star Trek, there is a substance called [Latinum](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Latinum) which can't be replicated. Incidentally, the same substance becomes very expensive and pretty much a substitute for money. The fact that the Federation is *nominally* a moneyless system (and it isn't, they have Federation credits) doesn't mean that there isn't some kind of a currency involved.

Whatever is rare, impossible to easily reproduce and sufficient durable and resistant to elements has the potential to carry intrinsic value and serve the function of money in an economic system.

Also, money [doesn't have to have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparta) intrinsic value. (Although I would argue that in these cases the *real* intrinsic value is in its issuer's military strength, but that's a different issue altogether)

Comment: It's not just latinum that can't be replicated -- it can't make dilithium or antimatter either.

Comment: @Plutor: Exactly, which makes them expensive. If dilithium and antimatter were less reactive and dangerous they would've served as a money substitute too.

Comment: @GoranJovic Dilithium, at least, _is_ very rare and [non-reactive](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Elaan_of_Troyius_(episode)).

Comment: Nevermind pepper, *clothing* is the real "totally cheap now, unbelievably expensive pre-industrial age" item. People would include their clothing in their wills, right alongside their furniture and other valuables.