# How do goods and services trade hands in the Star Trek universe with no monetary system to regulate value?

Tags: star-trek

I'm still unclear how Federation 'credits' work and who decides or assigns who gets how much. Does everyone get the same number of credits assigned to them or are credits assigned based upon position held or duties performed? Can someone increase their credit allotment by doing something different, special or extraordinary? Can everyone buy a spaceship, a yacht or a vineyard?

Note: Since there may be no answer to this in the episodes and movies, **answers can include info from tie-in novels, etc.**

Comment: Also related, but less so: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23580/what-happens-to-humans-that-choose-not-to-work-or-to-join-starfleet, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/how-to-reconcile-the-cashless-human-federation-society-with-human-traders-and-me

Comment: Interesting how this is going... I see no answer to the question in those threads. There's the standard talk of, "Humans have moved beyond the need to acquire goods and seek to better themselves", and vague references to 'credits' and "Put it on my account". There's also references to barter type exchanges. But no answer to how these Federation'credits' are identified, valued or assigned... Payback?

Comment: The linked threads *are* relevant to this, but I agree with @Morgan - this question still has no answer and it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @neilfein Not even the explicit `My question is, how do humans get "money" (credits, latinum, etc)?` in the third link DVK posted?

Comment: @Izkata - No, because that part of the question isn't actually answered. All that's stated there is that Federation currency has value, and that there's some sort of system in place in the Federation to deal with allocation of resources. This can't be answered within canon, though; the only possible way of getting an answer woud be in the tie-in novels, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @Morgan - This is not answered in the TV episodes and the movies. Would an answer from the Star Trek licensed tie-in fiction serve? If so, this would further differentiate this question from the links in the above comments.

Comment: @Morgan - the answer to your question is a combindation of these, but IMHO best expressed by Keith's answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6960/976)

Comment: @neilfein - At this point I'm willing to expand the search to get the question answered. There must be a definitive answer available.

Comment: @Morgan - Have edited the question and cast a re-open vote.

Comment: Thank you @neilfein, I'm still unskilled at navigating the protocols here.

Comment: @neilfein - fair enough. Not a dupe after the edit. VTRO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has never, ever, ever been addressed in the 79 episodes of The Original Series, the 176 episodes of the Next Generation, the 173 episodes of Deep Space Nine, the 168 episodes of Voyager, or the 97 episodes of Enterprise.

The only time we see any economy in action is in Deep Space 9, and it was all commerce with outsiders. Federation citizen obviously get paid something, because we see them use that money to buy things at various points of the series. Bartering is still around because we see it used in both Voyager and Deep Space 9. Beyond that, nobody knows. There aren't even enough data points to come up with a guess. I mean, you obviously can't just walk up and buy a Galaxy-class starship, but nobody blinks twice when they hand Scotty a shuttlecraft.

So... yeah. No data. No explanation.

Comment: I blinked twice. But only because I had something in my eye.

Comment: Look at Scotty's honest sad eyes. Wouldn't YOU hand him a shuttlecraft?

Comment: @Xantec - Don't blink. Just... don't.

Comment: @neilfein I don't recall seeing any Angels on the Enterprise.